# JLabel text split

Tags: java, swing, text, split, jlabel

i called a text from databse to jlabel, but the text is in 1 row, i want to split the text

```
try {
                String sql="SELECT Leírás FROM Filmlista WHERE Cím like'Fűrész'"; 
                PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

                    while (rs.next()) {
                        String name=rs.getString("Leírás");
                        foglab1.setText(name);
                        String[] parts=name.split("@");
                        String part1=parts[0];
                        String part2=parts[1];                     
                    }
```

so i have a long text and i want split it when he found @ character

Comment: please is there some reason to post repeatly quite the same questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HTML Luke :)

```
label.setText("<html>" + part1 + "<br>" + part2 + "</html>");
```

Comment: Would be better to do `label.setText(part1 + "\n" + part2);`

Comment: @3751_Creator Make your own swing ;) or use extension (probably commercial), which provides such components